# Is there a way to convert a .rofl file to .mp4 or .avi?

Tags: league-of-legends, recording

While using the League of Legends replay system, I found a nice replay that I like. I want to use it in a video, but my editing software cannot use .rofl files. Is there any way to convert the .rofl file to something I can use?

I did some quick searches to no avail.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about gaming.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question since League of Legends replays are often used in game-coaching and game-analysis. (Be it in a classic video format or in a .rofl file). This is an important topic especially in **professional gaming**.

Comment: @Jutschge Agreed. This is a file format specific to LoL. If we close this one, we should also be closing questions about screenshots, game file structure, etc...

Comment: @MageXy Uh.  We *do* close questions about game file structure.  That said, it seems like this file format is specific to LoL, and needs the client to even interpret them.  Seems to pretty clearly gaming specific.  Whether this is professional gaming or not is a side issue.

Comment: @Frank We do? That's news to me. A search for "[where is folder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=where+is+folder)" gives a heck of a lot of results, and most of them are not closed (or if they are, it's for being a dupe).

Comment: @MageXy Oh, we're using different definitions.  Trying to find a file, yeah, that's fine.  Trying to **decode** a file so it's human readable is the definition I was using.

Comment: @Frank Oh, I see. Yeah, I agree, that's off-topic - in most cases. Even there I have some reservations, but this isn't the time or place for that discussion.

Comment: I have a solution running on cloud. I pick the camera mode and generate the movie. It’s not cheap to do this. How much would people pay per replay to convert to mp4? $1?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `*.rofl` files contain only binary game data and no media frames.
For example a very simplified layout of the file could look like:

```
id   | champ. name | action | parameters
0000 | annie       | move   | 155 | 188
0001 | fizz        | attack | annie
```

and so on.

With this data the client is able to "reproduce" the game you just played.
If they recorded movie data instead there would be certain disadvantages:

- File size would probably be bigger
- Movie is bound to a fixed resolution
- Can't move the camera around in the spectator view

If you want to record that game play in a common movie format you can use the [built-in recorder](https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/developer-corner/2JWmR6sF-replays-are-live-in-the-new-client-faq-pro-tips).

> Just click the red Record Button on the new Annotated Timeline to start recording, (watch your sick play), then click again
>   to stop.
>   We’re calling these video clips “Highlights” and they’re in
>   the .webm format. Your Highlight will be saved on your computer in the
>   following location:
>        C:\Users\Username\Documents\LeagueofLegends\Highlights

Comment: How long can a single "Highlight" be? I can't record the whole match, can I?

Comment: I don't have the game installed so I can't really tell you, but I think the highlight is somewhat limited in it's length. For a full record I think the tools you mentioned are better suited - also because tools like Fraps can save the movie in a raw format for higher-quality editing (if needed).

Comment: And because you wrote this nice answer, you now have reputation to comment

Comment: "Since my reputation is too low to write comments I'll formulate an answer." There's no reason to remark on this fact since *that's the way the system is supposed to work*. Answers are nice.

Comment: ooooh, that makes sense now that i think about it.

Comment: I just tested it. It appears that there's no limit to the amount of time that a Highlight can go for. I recorded an entire 20 minute clip before calling it quits. The one major downside is that the resulting webm file is not very good quality. As a rough estimate, it looks to be about 1280x720 resolution, but with a lot of compression artifacts.

Answer (score 39):

No, there is no way to directly convert .rofl files to any other video format. This is because they are not video files themselves - they just contain "spectator data" so that the game client knows what actions happened at what times, which allows it to replay those actions in sequence for your viewing pleasure.

If you want to make an actual video recording, you'll need some kind of screen-recording software. There's a whole bunch of options - [OBS](https://obsproject.com/), [Plays.TV](http://plays.tv/home), and [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) are probably the most commonly used ones, but there's tons more too. These will record to actual video files (.avi or .mp4, usually) that you can then convert or use as you please.

As mentioned in another answer, you can use the built-in recorder as well, if you just want to save some clips. The result of using the built-in recorder is .webm file, which is a lightweight, web-friendly video file. After testing it, I can't see any hard limit on the amount of time that a single highlight can take (I was able to take 20 minutes of video without any problems). However, the quality of that recording isn't the greatest. I don't have a tool to take exact measurements, but I would estimate the resolution is about 1280x720. There are a lot of compression artifacts, though, so it doesn't look very crisp or high definition.

Comment: This answer is OK, but **please** read [the one by Michael Pittino](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309509/164183).

Comment: @mgarciaisaia I did read it - in fact, I commented on it already. It's a very good answer! However, if you want to record a whole game, the Highlights feature is unfortunately not going to be enough.

Comment: this is still the best answer

Comment: Windows 10 users do not have to use third-party software, because [they ported Xbox DVR](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160607-00/?p=93605).

Answer (score 2):

"replay" files for games are generally just instructions to the game engine, not actual video.

So if you want to convert them to an actual video you will most likely need to replay them in the game while recording the output of the game with a screen-recording soloution.

Comment: This answer adds nothing new.

Comment: The other answers seem to imply that you would have to initially record to a video format. I do not see any reason why that would be the case rather than simply playing the replay file and recording the results.

Comment: @PeterGreen The other answers imply the opposite. There's a build in recorder, which can be substituted by an external one. However it just looks nicer with the built in one. With that said, this isn't wrong, just doesn't add anything new