# How can I view different camera angles in spectator mode?

Tags: league-of-legends, recording

I noticed when people post their League of Legends games on YouTube they usually include close up face shots of the champions, from 3rd person, and all sorts of angles. I've been editing my videos by first recording highlights within the game using the platform RiotGames has set up.

I want to make more interesting videos but I can't figure out how to get different camera angles when I'm recording. I'm curious if it is another program that records the game while I'm playing that has this feature.

Example of a Video that uses the different camera angles technique:

This video is gorsky's. I would like to make my own videos with those types of shots but I only get the shots from birds eye view currently.

Answer (score 1):

This is done using a third party tool which modifies how the camera behaves during spectator mode. Though several different tools exist, I believe the most widely used one is the [SkinSpotlights Creative Suite](http://www.skinspotlights.com/p/creator-suite.html), which has been used to make the popular champion skin demonstration videos. This tool allows for free camera movement (in spectator mode *only*), including zooming in and out further than normal, tilting the camera, and other features. (You will still need a screen recorder of some type to record the actual footage, however. Take a look at [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/309473/145980) for some options to record spectator games.)

As with any third party software that modifies how the game works, you could technically be banned for using this program according to the EULA for LoL. However, this particular program is fairly widely used and Riot is not targeting users of the software for bans, so you should be okay to use it.